# Can two apps in one iPhone can be connected to same peripheral?

Tags: mac, bluetooth, mobile-device-management, multitasking, peripheral

I have to connect two apps to Bluetooth band (peripheral) at the same time and in same device. Please Guide.

Answer (score 1):

The Bluetooth connection is established between the phone and the device - the device does not exclusively connect to an individual application.

To answer the question a Bluetooth device can be used with multiple apps that are designed to work with it. For example, a Bluetooth speaker works with the Music app, it also works with YouTube etc.

Your device may have limitations that I am not aware of but without more information I can only tell you know Bluetooth works